# Creating variables in r

Tags: r

I have a problem with r; I have to create the variable "year" in my dataset but I am not able to create a variable whose values increase by 1 (the first value is 1991, the second 1992 etc...). Could you hel me please?

Comment: Please provide more detail.

Comment: Share the code of your attempt and point out specific problems please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a sequence of years from 1991 to, say, 2100, you could do it like this:

```
years<-1991:2100
```